# PHP : Validation errors pops up on the loading page

Tags: php, html, mysql, validation

I'm currently creating a login form. I want the validation errors to show after hitting "Login"

I've already added `if(isset($_POST['login']))`

This is my code for the query

```html
<?php

session_start();
$mail = $pass = "";
$errors = array();

$db = mysqli_connect('192.x.y.z','root','1234','LUCA','3306');


if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $mail = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']);
}

    if(empty($mail)){
        array_push($errors, "Email is required");
    }
    if(empty($pass)){
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }

    if(count($errors) == 0 ){
        $pass = $pass;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM login where email ='$mail' AND pw='$pass'";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
        {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $mail;

            header('home.html');
            exit();

        }else{
            array_push($errors, "Wrong Email/Password");
        }
    }

?>
```

This is my form

```html
<?php include('server.php');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Student Zone | LUCA Academy</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/login.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login-reg-panel">
    <div class="login-info-box">
      <label id="label-register" for="log-reg-show">Login</label>
      <input type="radio" name="active-log-panel" id="log-reg-show" checked="checked">
    </div>

    <div class="register-info-box">
      <img src="img/luca-lg.png">
    </div>
    <div class="white-panel">
      <div class="login-show">
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
          <?php include('validation.php'); ?>
          <h2>LOGIN</h2>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
          <input type="submit" name="login">
          <a href="">Forgot password?</a>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php if (count($errors) > 0): ?>

<div class="error">
  <?php foreach($errors as $error): ?>
  <p>
    <?php echo $error ?>
  </p>
  <?php endforeach ?>

</div>

<?php endif ?>
```

Thanks in advance for any advice and assistance

Comment: I removed JS and HTML. There is neither in your question. I also removed the snippet. It is not runnable. How does the form look like and how is the data sent to the server?

Comment: @mplungjan I've edited the question and added the form

Comment: you should wrap your validation on a function and call the function on form submit

Comment: Where is the `if (count($errors) == 0 ) echo "success"; else echo '<pre>'; print_r($errors); echo '</pre>';` before the `?>` ?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I've managed to solve it by myself. It was a curly bracket closed early

Comment: Do not store plaintext passwords in DB. Use `password_hash()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can carry errors with the session variable from index.php

```
if (!empty($errors)) {
   $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
} else {
   $newURL = 'http://your-after-login-page.com/after-login';
   header('Location: '.$newURL);
}
```

Then in login page just check error and show the respective message

```
<div class="login-show">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        <?php include('validation.php'); ?>
            <h2>LOGIN</h2>
            <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['errors']) && !empty($_SESSION['errors'])){
                echo '<ul>';
                foreach($_SESSION['errors'] as $error){
                    echo '<li style="color: #A52A2A;">' . $error . '</li>';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
            }
        ?>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" name="login">
        <a href="">Forgot password?</a>
    </form>
</div>
```